# Read from multiple sources using Nifi, group topics in Kafka and subscribe with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

We use Apache Nifi to get data from multiple sources like Twitter and Reddit in specific interval (for example 30s). Then we would like to send it to Apache Kafka and probably it should somehow group both Twitter and Reddit messages into 1 topic so that Spark would always receive data from both sources for given interval at once.

Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sebastian What you describe is basic NiFI routing.   You would just route both Twitter and Redis to the same downstream Kafka Producer and same Topic.    After you get data into NiFi from each service, you should run it to UpdateAttribute and set attribute topicName to what you want for each source.   If there are additional steps per Data Source do them after Update Attribute and before PublishKafka.

If you code all the upstream routes as above, you could route all the different Data Sources to PublishKafka processor using ${topicName} dynamically.